# Why the application cache has been removed?

Tags: html

From MDN：

> This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Avoid using it and update existing code if possible; see the compatibility table at the bottom of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Because it was replaced by Service Workers.

AppCache has a not so good API design and Service Worker can be used more flexible.